# Грамматическая основа в предложении "Из письма Цицерона к Тирону"

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая грамматическая основа в предложении "Из письма Цицерона к Тирону, своему вольноотпущеннику и писарю".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Это неполное предложение. Основа только предполагается: ЭТО ЕСТЬ (это взято, это цитируется и т.д.). Из письма - обстоятельство.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Ох, не видел Вашего ответа. Но согласен. А идею считать всю фразу целиком одним главным членом не разделяете?

Comment: Она мне показалась интересной. Думаю.

Answer (score 1):

А почему это вообще предложение, а не распространенное словосочетание, взятое в качестве названия?

Вряд ли корректно достраивать синтаксическую конструкцию, тем самым изменяя ее вид.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос. никогда не думал, что подобные пометки, обычно в скобках или в качестве условного названия даваемые, можно считать предложением и выделять основу.

Но если так, то стоит, видимо, либо считать основа опущена ("***указанное есть выдержка*** из письма..."), либо трактовать предложение  как назывное нераспространненое (всё предложение - главный член).